# anonymous function in LINQ query error

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-function

Here is the code that I am trying implement:

```
var query = from line in thedata
            orderby () =>  {
                int a = line.IndexOf("Score=\"");
                if (line[a + "Score=\"".Length + 1] == '-') {
                    return
                        int.Parse(line[a + "Score=\"".Length + 1].ToString()
                      + line[a + "Score=\"".Length + 2]);
                }

                return int.Parse(line[a + "Score=\"".Length + 1].ToString());
            }
            select line;
```

Where `thedata` is a list of strings.

The compiler shows an error on the `orderby` (the type arguments cannot be inferred). How can I rewrite this function to resolve this error?  As a side point, is there a better way of getting negative numbers in this type of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your "is there a better way" question, how about this: since the score is apparently always a single digit (perhaps preceded by a `-`), we can use a regex to pull out the score, define a range variable with `let`, then order by it:

```
// With a positive look-behind assertion for Score="
// Capture:
//  an optional minus
//  then
//  a digit
Regex score = new Regex("(?<=Score=\")-?\\d");

string[] thedata = new[] { "Score=\"5\"", "Score=\"-2\"" };

var query = from line in thedata
            let scoreAsString = score.Match(line).Value
            orderby int.Parse(scoreAsString)
            select line;

foreach (var outputLine in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outputLine);
}
```

produces

```
Score="-2"
Score="5"
```

The positive look-behind assertion `(?<=Score=\")` says to only consider matching if the previous text is `Score="`; only the optional `-` and the digit are actually captured into the `Match`, though.

Comment: And if it can be more than two characters (20, or -10)?

Comment: @soandos put a `+` (meaning 'one or more') after `\\d` in the regex definition

Answer (score 5):

Query expressions don't support that syntax.

You should call `OrderBy` directly:

```
var query = data.OrderBy(line => { ... });
```

Comment: Where the braces are my function? And what does the error mean?

Comment: The compiler is trying to write `OrderBy(line => () => { ... })`.  The expressions in a query are _bodies_ of lambda expressions.